# function to retrieve member function pointer with n arguments

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to implement a function to retrieve the function pointer of overloaded member functions with n arguments. So e.g. for the following class:

```cpp
struct Test
{
    int func(int i1);
    int func(int i1, int i2);
    int func(int i1, int i2, int i3);
};
```

I need to retrieve one specific overload of `Test::func`. I already have the following implementation:

```cpp
template<int Num> struct Overload {};


template<> struct Overload<0>
{
    template<class Ret, class Class>
    static auto from(Ret (*func)()) { return func; }

    template<class Ret, class Class>
    static auto from(Ret (Class::*meth)()) { return meth; }

    template<class Ret, class Class>
    static auto from(Ret (Class::*meth)() const) { return meth; }
};

template<> struct Overload<2>
{
    template<class Ret, class Class, class Arg1, class Arg2>
    static auto from(Ret (*func)(Arg1, Arg2)) { return func; }

    template<class Ret, class Class, class Arg1, class Arg2>
    static auto from(Ret (Class::*meth)(Arg1, Arg2)) { return meth; }

    template<class Ret, class Class, class Arg1, class Arg2>
    static auto from(Ret (Class::*meth)(Arg1, Arg2) const) { return meth; }
};
```

This implementation works as expected, but needs to be implemented separately for each argument count.
From my understanding this would require https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4072.html which was rejected, but I could be missing something. Is there a way to derive the arguments from the template argument `Num` in C++17/C++20?

Edit: Some clarifications regarding comments / answers

1. why not just use the arguments as template arguments:
   I already have a function for this purpose:

```cpp
template<class... Args> struct OverloadArgs
{
    template<class Ret>
    static auto from(Ret (*func)(Args...)) {return func;}
    ...
};
```

E.g. for swizzling I simply have multiple overloads with different arg counts and it is a lot more concise to specify `Overload<4>::from(&Test::swizzle)` instead of `OverloadArgs<int, int, int, int>::from(&Test::swizzle)`

2. This is used to wrap functions/classes to Python. As described in 1) it can be more concise to overload on arg count instead of arg type in some cases, which is why I would like to have both.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you plan to do with overloads that take the same number but different types of parameters?

Comment: I have a similar implementation which directly allows the user to specify the arg types:
`template<class... Args> struct OverloadArgs`

Comment: Have a look at [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). You might just have to specify the function signature in its template so it can perform overload resolution. ie `auto memptr1 = std::mem_fn<int(int)>(&Test::func)` and `auto memptr2 = std::mem_fn<int(int, int)>(&Test::func)`.

Comment: Are types restricted to `int`? (in that case `std::index_sequence` and a "`using always_t<I, T> = T;`" might do the trick).

Comment: The types are not restricted to int. Usually it will be n times the same type, since for varying types the `OverloadArgs` impl would likely be more readable.

Comment: `OverloadArgs<4, int>` might be possible (using `OverloadArgs_impl<int, int, int, int>` or equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying number of arguments, you can specify argument types

```
template<class... Args> struct Overload
{
    template<class Ret, class Class>
    static auto from(Ret(Class::* meth)(Args...)) { return meth; }
};

int main()
{
     Test t;  
     auto p2 = Overload<int, int>::from(&Test::func);  
     auto p0 = Overload<>::from(&Test::func);
     (t.*p0)();
     (t.*p2)(1,2);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPD**

Well... My knowledges are only enough for the following proposal

```
#define Overload_0 Overload<>
#define Overload_1 Overload<int>
#define Overload_2 Overload<int,int>

int main()
{
     Test t;  
     auto p2 = Overload_2::from(&Test::func);
     auto p0 = Overload_0::from(&Test::func);
     (t.*p0)();
     (t.*p2)(1,2);
     
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already have a class like this. However in some cases I would like to overload simply based on the arg count.

Comment: @maxbachmann i don't know if any meta-programming can do the trick in your case. My best thought is to use preprocessor

Comment: Yes thats what I do right now. It is not the most pretty thing, but does the job

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completly understand your goal, but I think [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) can solve this.
Template parameter pack (in this case named `Args`) allows you to pass a variable number of parameters.

```
struct Test {
    int func(int i1);
    int func(int i1, int i2);
    int func(int i1, int i2, int i3);
};

template<class Ret, class Class, class... Args>
auto From(Ret(Class::*meth)(Args...)) {
    return meth;
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    auto f = From<int, Test, int, int, int>(&Test::func);
    int result = std::invoke(f, t, 10, 11, 12);
}
```

I'm curious how you intend to use this, but there's probably a different and better approach.