# generating tuple of lambdas for function overloads

Tags: c++, c++20

I need to wrap some functions with default arguments to call them from a different programming language. For this purpose I have to generate a tuple of possible overloads. E.g. for:

```cpp
int func(void* arg1, int arg2 = -1)
{
    return 1;
}
```

I would need to generate the following code:

```cpp
std::make_tuple(
    [](ArgType<decltype(&func), 0> arg0) {
        return func(arg0);
    },
    [](ArgType<decltype(&func), 0> arg0 , ArgType<decltype(&func), 1> arg1) {
        return func(arg0 , arg1);
    }
)
```

My current implementation looks like this:

```cpp
#define ARG_IN(N, func) ArgType<decltype(&func), N> arg##N
#define ARG(N, _) arg##N

// insert macro recursively using PP_OBSTRUCT(OVERLOAD_FUNCTIONS_INDIRECT
// while the condition PP_WHEN(PP_PRIMITIVE_COMPARE holds true
#define OVERLOAD_FUNCTIONS(func, minArgs, numArgs) \
    PP_WHEN(PP_PRIMITIVE_COMPARE(minArgs, numArgs)) \
        (PP_OBSTRUCT(OVERLOAD_FUNCTIONS_INDIRECT)()(func, minArgs, PP_DEC(numArgs)), ) \
    [](PP_REPEAT(numArgs, ARG_IN, PP_COMMA, func)) \
    { \
        return func(PP_REPEAT(numArgs, ARG, PP_COMMA, ~)); \
    }
#define OVERLOAD_FUNCTIONS_INDIRECT() OVERLOAD_FUNCTIONS

#define OVERLOADS(func, minArgs, maxArgs) \
    std::make_tuple(PP_EVAL(OVERLOAD_FUNCTIONS(func, minArgs, maxArgs)))
```

The PP Macros are largely similar to boost preprocessor. The overloads can be generated using:

```cpp
auto func_overloads = OVERLOADS(func, 1, 2)
```

While this approach works, I would prefer to reduce the amount of preprocessor code generation involved in this. There are two problematic parts:

1. func cannot be passed into a template, since this would already require it to be the correct overload. It would be fine to keep this in a macro.
2. it is completely unclear to me how to create the wrapper lambda. If we did use a template based approach at this point we would have the function name from the macro and the argument count as an integer e.g. like this:

```cpp
#define OVERLOADS(func, minArgs, maxArgs) \
    [] <size_t... I> (std::index_sequence<I...>) { \
        return std::make_tuple(GET_OVERLOAD(func, I + minArgs)...); \
    } (std::make_index_sequence<maxArgs - minArgs>{})
```

Is there any way to reduce the macro usage in this implementation?

Comment: as long as you're using `decltype(&func)` there is already no ambiguous overload (unless it's a callable object).

Comment: This basically has to be a macro. Unary `func` can only be spelled `func(arg)` in code, not any other way. Once you capture it as a template parameter or something, it becomes only invocable as a binary function.

Comment: yes this has to be a macro. The func part does not really bother me as much as the boost preprocessor usage. This is one of the last places this is used in our code base and we would really love to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this with templates underneath the first macro, you could do something horrifying like this.

First, a very basic, inefficient `function_traits` implementation (which you can swap out for whatever you're using with that `ArgType` thing):

```
template<class T> struct function_traits;  

template<class R, class... Args> 
struct function_traits<R(Args...)> {
    template <std::size_t i>
    struct arg {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
    };
};
```

Given that you write an `OVERLOADS` macro:

```
#define OVERLOADS(func, minArgs, maxArgs)\
    detail::get_overloads<minArgs, maxArgs,\
        decltype([](auto&&... args) {\
            return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);\
        }),\
        function_traits<decltype(func)>>()
```

Now bear with me.

We pass the type of a lambda which perfect-forwards arguments to your desired function. This is how we capture the overload set. Later we'll make use of the fact that lambda types are default-constructible in C++20.

Then:

```
template <std::size_t minArgs, std::size_t maxArgs, class Lifted, class FuncTraits>
auto get_overloads() {
    return [] <std::size_t... I> (std::index_sequence<I...>) { 
        return std::make_tuple(get_overload<Lifted, FuncTraits, I+minArgs>()...); 
    } (std::make_index_sequence<maxArgs - minArgs + 1>{});
}
```

This is basically what you had in your version of `OVERLOADS` at the bottom, just as a function template for clarity. We're going to make a tuple with all the overloads requested.

We then make a function template which default-constructs a lambda which is given to it, forwarding all arguments (not taking by forwarding ref is intentional, as we'll be supplying `Args` manually):

```
template <class Lifted, class... Args>
auto perform_call(Args... args) {
    return Lifted{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then we do some magic in `get_overload` to get a pointer to the correct specialization of `perform_call` that we want:

```
template <class Lifted, class FuncTraits, std::size_t I>
auto get_overload() {
    return []<std::size_t... J> (std::index_sequence<J...>) {
        return &perform_call<Lifted, typename FuncTraits::template arg<J>::type...>;
    }(std::make_index_sequence<I>{});
}
```

I did say it was horrifying.

But it appears to work fine if I've understood your issue correctly: https://godbolt.org/z/qa1GP87M7

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. Even though I agree this is pretty horrifying.  Is there something comparable if I have a function with multiple overloads and I want to select one of the overloads based on the argument count? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781664/function-to-retrieve-member-function-pointer-with-n-arguments

Comment: Hmmmmm are the argument types always strictly overlapping? And there are never two overloads with the same number of arguments? Like, you have `foo(int)`, `foo(int,bool)` and `foo(int,bool,double)`, but never `foo(int)`, `foo(int,bool)` and `foo(double,bool,double)`?

Comment: At least so far they are and I think in the really exceptional case that they do overlap it would be better to write out the types for clarity. So this restriction would be fine.

Comment: It would definitely be doable if the user code explicitly passed in the overload with the most parameters, like `OVERLOADS(foo, 1, 3, static_cast<void(*)(int,bool,double)>(foo))`. I'm trying to think of a way to somehow grab a pointer to the overload which has exactly `maxArgs` parameters, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: I thought of doing `#define GET_BIGGEST_OVERLOAD(func, maxArgs) []<class R, class... Args> requires (sizeof...(Args) == maxArgs) (R(*f)(Args...)) { return f; } (func)` but alas, resolution of function pointers doesn't work like that.

Comment: You could do something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/xscxr6nhP

Comment: yes this would probably work, even though `GET_BIGGEST_OVERLOAD` would still need to be generated